# VSCode #include errors involving plog library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have been in the process of re-learning c++ as I am on MacOS, my options for IDE's are limited. I arrived on VScode, as I figured learning how to properly customize and optimize a programming environment would pay dividends in the future.

What I am currently learning is debugging and logging, in my learning materials I have arrived on an open source library called plog and wished to activate it on VSCode

```
#include <plog/Log.h>
#include <plog/Initializers/RollingFileInitializer.h>
#include <iostream> 

int getUserInput()
{
    PLOGD <<"getUserInput() called"; 
    std::cout << "Enter a number : "; 
    int x{};
    std::cin >> x; 
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    plog::init(plog::debug, "Logfile.txt"); 
    PLOGD << "main() called"; 

    int x{getUserInput()}; 
    std::cout << "You entered: " << x << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see in my code, I have implemented plog's libraries, VSCode insists that it cannot find the libraries.

However, I have installed plog's header files into the following folder :

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/plog

I have tried placing the plog files into the c++ folder,

adding the "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/" to the "include" line in vsCodes intellisence or cplusplus include settings option,

I have tried placing plog in my work environment via git clone and adding the following header :

```
#include "plog/include/plog/Log.h"
#include "plog/Initializers/RollingFileInitializer.h"
```

The compiler will say it's fine and ergo no problems, but the linker says "No, I do not think so." and returns a fatal error, log.h not found

I think c++'s library might be located somewhere else on my macbook air and the c++ library I am looking at is not the right one?

I cannot be sure.

Comment: "_adding the "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/" to the "include" line in vsCodes intellisence or cplusplus include settings option,_" show **exactly** what you did to your settings.json/c_cpp_properties.json file.

Comment: exactly what I did? Meaning it should reveal problems if I include that line in include settings or will produce an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to include this 3rd party library, first I installed brew and then I installed cmake.

After installing cmake, what I did was the following :

Navigated to my file folder.

```
git clone https://github.com/SergiusTheBest/plog.git
cd plog
cmake -Bbuild
cd build
make
sudo make install
```

after that was done, plog was installed to my computer itself with no need to even adjust the includePath file in vsCode's settings.